# Mapping stored procedures in EF 6 to abstract types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My data model uses inheritance (which I'm trying to change...) but looks like:

```
abstract class Entity 
{
    public int foo { get; set; }
}

class Derived1 : Entity
{
    public int WidgetCount { get; Set; }
}

class Derived2 : Entity
{
    public int BarCount { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to retrieve the results of a query (or stored proc) that returns an Entity, but the `.ExecuteStoreCommand<T>` `.Translate<T>` and `.SqlQuery<T>` all fail because they can't create Entities, yet a query against the DbContext's `DbSet<Entity>` works and returns objects of the correct type (either Derived1 or Derived2).

Is there a way for me to query for Entities without using the DbSet?

Comment: What's the problem about DbSet? Do you need to hide DbSet<Entity>? You don't know Entity?

Comment: Performance. The query generated with my model is > 150kb, and it's called often. Roughly 3-4mb per page. I am working on a better solution, but until that's in place is like to offload some queries onto stored procs.

Comment: That's a big problem of EF... Firebird hangs with query > 64kb... Anyway, there is a tiny ORM (Dapper) that simply map from the result of a query to an entity (but no lazy load, no query generation, etc.).